# AngularJS digest inside a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, events

Supposedly I have the following HTML

```
<div ng-if="running">
    <div id="someid"></div>
</div>
<span ng-click="myfunc">Click</span>
```

In angular controller I set a function when click a button

```
$scope.myfunc = function(){
    $scope.running = true;

    //attach some jquery event
    $('#someid').on('animationend', function(){...})
}
```

I want to update the DOM right after `running=true` because if I dont or put the attached event somewhere else, it doesn't work because the DOM didnt exist yet. `ng-if` seems to remove it and it only shows the div only when the function ends. I tried `$scope.$digest()` right after running not work either and it shows error.

So what's the proper way to attach the event above?

Comment: It looks like a Directive would solve that - I would have a read about Angular directives and how you can manipulate the element and attach events to it :)

Comment: If you want you can see my example with an Angular directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using $timeout in your controller, in this way:

```
    myApp.controller('exampleController', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {

                $scope.myfunc = function(){
                   $scope.running = true;            

                   var timeout = $timeout(function({
                     $('#someid').on('animationend', function(){...})  

                     $timeout.cancel(timeout);  
                   }, 0)
                }
            }]);
```

Shortly speaking, [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) with 0 as interval lets you to wait for the next digest cycle.

Comment: This is a workaround. Please see my example, using an Angular directive.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-if="running">
    <div id="someid"></div>
</div>
<span ng-click="myfunc()">Click</span>

//in controller
    $('#someid').on('animationend', function(){
     $scope.$apply(function() {
       //$scope.blabla = 'hello';
     })
    });

$scope.myfunc = function(){
    $scope.running = true;
}
```

But you should make a directive

EDIT:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.directive('startAnimate', function () {
 return {
  scope: {
   startAnimate: '@', //animation name (string)
   seconds: '@', //duration in seconds (int)
   startOnCreation: '=?', //start on creation of element (boolean) - optional
   onAnimationEnd: '=?', //callback at end - optional
   workspace: '=?' //create an object to allow two-way data binding with primitive values (boolean, int, ...) - optional
  },
  link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
   var animation = scope.startAnimate + ' ' + scope.seconds + 's';

   if (!scope.workspace) {
    scope.workspace = {};
   }

   scope.workspace.running = false;

   var setElementSAnimation = function (animation) {
    element.css({
     WebkitAnimation: animation,
     animation: animation
    });
   }

   var startAnimation = function () {
    setElementSAnimation(animation);

    scope.workspace.running = true;
   }

   if (scope.startOnCreation) {
    startAnimation();
   }

   element.click(function () {
    scope.$apply(function () {
     startAnimation();
    });
   });

   if (!scope.onAnimationEnd) {
    scope.onAnimationEnd = function () { };
   }

   var oldAnimationEnd = scope.onAnimationEnd;

   scope.onAnimationEnd = function () {
    oldAnimationEnd();

    //clean animation to allow to repeat it
    setElementSAnimation('');

    scope.$apply(function () {
     scope.workspace.running = false;
    })
   };

   element.on("webkitAnimationEnd animationend", scope.onAnimationEnd);
  }
 }
});

app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
 $scope.myfunc = function () {
  alert('finish');
 }

 $scope.showElement = false;

 $scope.workspace = {
  running: false
 }
});
```

```css
#myDIV {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background: orange;
 position: relative;
}

@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
 from {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
 }

 to {
  top: 80px;
  left: 160px;
 }
}

@keyframes mymove {
 from {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
 }

 to {
  top: 80px;
  left: 160px;
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="myCtrl">
 <div data-ng-if="workspace.running">
  Yes, it's running!
 </div>

 <div id="myDIV" data-ng-if="showElement" data-start-animate="mymove" data-start-on-creation="true" data-seconds="4" data-on-animation-end="myfunc" data-workspace="workspace">
  <span>Click me to start the animation.</span>
 </div>

 <button type="button" data-ng-click="showElement = !showElement">Toggle element</button>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('#someid')` not exists because `ng-if` remove that div from the DOM

Comment: "But you should make a directive" I answered in August of last year. Sorry for the delay, now I showed you the correct way.

Comment: There's too much code compare to the accepted answer... ty for trying

Comment: Accepted answer is a workaround, bad practice. The code you have to see is the html code. The directive is reusable.
data-start-animate="mymove" data-start-on-creation="true" data-seconds="4" data-on-animation-end="myfunc" data-workspace="workspace"